# becameVisible hook in an EmberJS View

Tags: ember.js

Can anybody enlighten me on how to use the `becameVisible` hook in an Ember.View? If I use it in the same way as the `didInsertElement` hook it doesn't seem to fire when I expect it to.

The case is that I have multiple tabs, and one of them contains a google map. I need to trigger a refresh on the map as soon as that tab is selected.

The documentation regarding the hook can be found [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/), around halfway the page, at Lifecycle Hooks

I'm on Ember 1.3.2

Comment: I can't find any documentation for a becameVisible hook, http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html could you provide a link etc.

Comment: @MartinElvar I added a reference. It can be found in [the explanation of the view layer](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/) at the Lifecycle Hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to answer the title in regards to the `becameVisible` hook on the view. This hook only fires when the `isVisible` property of the view changes. By default the `isVisible` property is set to true on views. So if you toggle that property on a view, or set it to false the view will be hidden and that will cause the `becameHidden` hook to fire when it is set back to true the `becameVisible` hook will fire.

So lets say on the index template we have a link with an action targeted to the view and a view name `App.MyDiv` that we will use to illustrate the hooks becameVisible/becameHidden firing on that view:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

     <a href="#" {{action 'hide' target="view"}}>Hide that Div</a>

     {{view App.MyDiv}}

  </script>
```

We need to handle the hide action and since its target to the view we will hand it there then get the view App.MyDiv that I set to "hidemydiv" using the viewName property so I could grab it by name and then set the `isVisible` property:

```
 App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
   actions: {
     hide: function() {
       console.log(this.get('hidemydiv').toggleProperty('isVisible'));
     }
   }
 });
```

Now in our App.MyDiv View definition: we could have something like this:

```
 App.MyDiv = Ember.View.extend({
   viewName: 'hidemydiv',
   templateName: 'myDiv',

   didInsertElement: function() {
     console.log('My Div: didInsertElement');
   },

   becameVisible: function() {
     console.log('My Div: Became Visible');
   },

   becameHidden: function() {
     console.log('My Div: Became Hidden');
   }
 });
```

Here is a JSBin to show what happens when the `isVisible` property is toggled on a view.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nuniqawi/1/edit

In relation to your question you could have a action on the tab that when pressed it calls some sort of rerender action on the map.